# ¿Cómo abrir un archivo .TXT con python y manejar los nombres de archivos?

Tags: python-3.x

estuve intentando abrir un archivo .txt con pandas, para trabajar con los nombres de dichos archivos. El bendito txt tiene aprox 41.000 filas, este formato:

```
    Directorio: P:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                      
-a---      22/05/2019  12:51 p.m.      26075 1.jpg                                                                                     
-a---      22/05/2019  12:51 p.m.      13316 10.jpg                                                                                    
-a---      22/05/2019  12:51 p.m.      22972 100.jpg        
...      
-a---      22/05/2019  01:24 p.m.      49183 9999.jpg                                                                                  
-a---      23/05/2019  09:38 a.m.   11566430 imagenes.txt
```

(podría borrar la primer linea y la última, si fuese necesario).

Intentos :
1)

```
 data = pd.read_csv('P:/test/imagenes.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
```

error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
>   5, saw 6

2)

```
df = pd.read_table('P:/test/imagenes.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

3)

```
df = pd.read_csv('P:/test/imagenes.txt', delimiter = "\t")
df = pd.read_csv('P:/test/imagenes.txt', delimiter= '\s+', index_col=False)
```

Mismo error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener los datos?. Copié el .txt en un excel, y lo pude abrir pero los datos se ven de la siguiente manera:

```
df = pd.read_csv('P:/test/images.csv', delimiter = "\t")
```

pero para poder acceder a la columna tengo que hacer asi:

```
df['Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                      '][1]
```

output:

```
'-a---      22/05/2019  12:51 p.m.      26075 1.jpg                                                                                     '
```

de esta fila solo me interesa "1.jpg"

Comment: tu archivo no tiene forma de csv. En lugar de querer abrirlo como csv, podrías simplemente abrirlo con `open("P:/test/images.csv")` y leerlo por lineas.

Comment: Parsearlo como csv no es fácil... básicamente porque no es ni de lejos un csv válido. ¿Solo te interesa la columna Name? Los errores de codificación pueden ser debidos a que la codificación del archivo sea UTF-16 (hay más posibilidades), ¿puedes confirmar la codificación que tiene el archivo?

Comment: @FJSevilla Solo era necesario la columna Name, ya encontré la manera de acceder . No se como obtener la codificación UTF

Comment: Hola. Por favor, pon la solución *como respuesta* y acéptala. Así otros sabrán que tiene respuesta y cómo lo resolviste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:** Como lo único que necesitaba eran los nombres de los archivos. Anterior a esto habia creado un TXT desde la terminal. Pero investigando por la web me topé con una posible solución, y es la siguiente:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

jpgs = [arch for arch in listdir('P:/test/') if isfile(join('P:/test/', arch))]
```

en `jpgs` se guardan los nombre de los archivos que se estaban buscando controlar.